# Swift - dynamicType in initializer of Subclass returns BaseClass instead

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

I'm trying to create a Abstract class that can fetch records from CloudKit and return the appropriate instances based on the subclass that called the fetch method.

The problem is the class method of the Base class doesn't return an instance of the Subclass. 
Run the following code in playgrounds:

```
class Base {
  class var value: String { return "Base" }
  class func doSomething() -> Self { // In Obj-C this would return instanceType
    println("doSomething() = \(self.value)")
    let object = self.init()
    return object
  }

  init() {
    println("init() = \(self.dynamicType.value)")
  }
}

class Sub: Base {
  override class var value: String { return "Sub" }

  override init() {
    super.init()
    println("Value = \(self.dynamicType.value)")
  }
}

println("Base")
let base = Base.doSomething() // type = Base

println()
println("Sub")
let sub = Sub.doSomething() // type = Base !!
```

For some reason when calling doSomething() on the Subclass, the initializer prints the value of the Base class property ("Base" instead of "Sub):

> Base doSomething() = Base 
>   init() = Base
>   
>   Sub doSomething() = Sub
>   init() = Base

Answer (score 0):

You should get the correct string value when you do a:

```
NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)
```